# Unable to compile C++ OpenCV2.4.9, Win7x64, Eclipse Mars, MinGW

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv

Little new to OpenCV, i've made some stuff in Java OpenCV, but limited with this lib, i've step to C/C++ with much difficulties!

**I've succeded building and running C OpenCV projects**, but seeing most of tutorials running on C++ version, i'm trying to make a simple "HelloCV":

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{

Mat img = imread("c:/lenna.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

namedWindow("MyWindow", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("MyWindow", img);

waitKey(0);
return 0;
}
```

I always get the following errors :

```
../src/mainCPP.cpp:12: undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::string const&, int)'
../src/mainCPP.cpp:14: undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(std::string const&, int)'
../src/mainCPP.cpp:15: undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
../src/mainCPP.cpp:15: undefined reference to `cv::imshow(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
../src/mainCPP.cpp:17: undefined reference to `cv::waitKey(int)'
src\maincpp.o: In function `ZN2cv3MatD1Ev':
C:/OpenCV_2.4.9/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:278: undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
src\maincpp.o: In function `ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv':
C:/OpenCV_2.4.9/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:367: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've followed about 4-5 installations tuto, but I only succed in crashing my projects!

My "working" settings :

- C/C++ Build -> GCC C++ Compiler -> Includes -> Include paths (-I) : path to my include folder ( "C:\OpenCV_2.4.9\opencv\build\include" )
- C/C++ Build -> GCC C++ Linker -> Libraries -> Library search path (-L) -> "C:\OpenCV_2.4.9\opencv\build\x86\vc11\lib",
  I know I've put the path to the x86 instead of x64 due to lib error like : "Not compatible system architecture"...!
- C/C++ Build -> GCC C++ Linker -> Libraries -> Libraries (-l) : opencv_core249, opencv_imgproc249 and highgui249 (i've tested including all libs but it's the same)

I've added the environment variable : C:\OpenCV_2.4.9\opencv\build\x86\vc11\bin (isn't it only for M$ Visual Studio?!)

Comment: i'm exploring this following way : i'm using ../build/x86/vc11/bin or vc10 or vc11 and they're all for Visual C++ compiler.... OpenCV had stop building binaries for minGW, so i had to compile them...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like openCV isn't getting installed properly. Try using Chocolatey, it can cleanly install the latest version of OpenCV on windows.